# How to sum elements at the same index in array of arrays into a single array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, grouping

Let's say that I have an array of arrays, like so:

```
[
  [0, 1, 3],
  [2, 4, 6],
  [5, 5, 7],
  [10, 0, 3]
]
```

How do I generate a new array that sums all of the values at each position of the inner arrays in javascript? In this case, the result would be: [17, 10, 19]. I need to be able to have a solution that works regardless of the length of the inner arrays. I think that this is possible using some combination of map and for-of, or possibly reduce, but I can't quite wrap my head around it. I've searched but can't find any examples that quite match this one.

Comment: What do you expect to do if some of the sub-arrays are different lengths.  Do you want that to be an error?  Or just use `0` for array elements in the shorter arrays that don't match up with the longer ones?

Comment: @jfriend00 that's a good question. Given that choice, I'd say use 0 for shorter arrays.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) in combination with [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```js
var array = [
        [0, 1, 3],
        [2, 4, 6],
        [5, 5, 7],
        [10, 0, 3]
    ],
    result = array.reduce(function (r, a) {
        a.forEach(function (b, i) {
            r[i] = (r[i] || 0) + b;
        });
        return r;
    }, []);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Update, a shorter approach by taking a map for reducing the array.

```js
var array = [[0, 1, 3], [2, 4, 6], [5, 5, 7], [10, 0, 3]],
    result = array.reduce((r, a) => a.map((b, i) => (r[i] || 0) + b), []);
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 12):

Using [Lodash 4](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#unzip):

```js
function sum_columns(data) {
  return _.map(_.unzip(data), _.sum);
}

var result = sum_columns([
  [1, 2],
  [4, 8, 16],
  [32]
]);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

#### For older Lodash versions and some remarks

Lodash 4 has changed the way `_.unzipWith` works, now the iteratee gets all the values passed as spread arguments at once, so we cant use the reducer style `_.add` anymore. With [Lodash 3](https://lodash.com/docs/3.10.1#unzipWith) the following example works just fine:

```js
function sum_columns(data) {
  return _.unzipWith(data, _.add);
}

var result = sum_columns([
  [1, 2],
  [4, 8, 16],
  [32],
]);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.js"></script>
```

`_.unzipWith` will insert `undefined`s where the row is shorter than the others, and `_.sum` treats undefined values as 0. (as of Lodash 3)

If your input data can contain `undefined` and `null` items, and you want to treat those as 0, you can use this:

```js
function sum_columns_safe(data) {
  return _.map(_.unzip(data), _.sum);
}

function sum_columns(data) {
  return _.unzipWith(data, _.add);
}

console.log(sum_columns_safe([[undefined]])); // [0]
console.log(sum_columns([[undefined]]));      // [undefined]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.js"></script>
```

This snipet works with Lodash 3, unfortunately I didn't find a nice way of treating undefined as 0 in Lodash 4, as now sum is changed so `_.sum([undefined]) === undefined`

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm not all that familiar with lodash, but it looks like I should check it out more. Looking at the docs, they have an example that uses _.unzipWith and _.add, like: return _.unzipWith(data, _.add). Would that work too?

Comment: Doesn't lodash have `flatten()`?

Comment: @hmlee yes, that's even better. The only difference is `_.map(_.unzip([[undefined]]), _.sum) -> [0]`, but `_.unzipWith([[undefined]], _.add) === [undefined]`

Comment: @binki it does, but it doesn't help in this case

Comment: @TamasHegedus How can I use lodash in v4, which executes with `(...group)`.

Comment: @Yi-TingLiu The above snippets wok just fine using Lodash v4, you don't have to use the ES6 spread syntax.

Comment: Hi @TamasHegedus! In lodash `4.17.11`, I got the differenc result `[5,10,16]` instead of `[37,10,16]`.

Comment: @Yi-TingLiu you are right! I don't have an explanation or solution out of the box, but I will do some research

Comment: @Yi-TingLiu I updated the post for Lodash 4, thanks for the notice!

Answer (score 5):

One-liner in `ES6`, with `map` and `reduce`

```js
var a = [ [0, 1, 3], [2, 4, 6], [5, 5, 7], [10, 0, 3] ];

var sum = a[0].map((_, i) => a.reduce((p, _, j) => p + a[j][i], 0));

document.write(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the nested arrays will always have the same lengths, concat and reduce can be used.

```js
    function totalIt (arr) {
        var lng = arr[0].length;
       return [].concat.apply([],arr)  //flatten the array
                .reduce( function(arr, val, ind){ //loop over and create a new array
                    var i = ind%lng;  //get the column
                    arr[i] = (arr[i] || 0) + val; //update total for column
                    return arr;  //return the updated array
                }, []);  //the new array used by reduce
    }
    
    var arr = [
      [0, 1, 3],
      [2, 4, 6],
      [5, 5, 7],
      [10, 0, 3]
    ];
    console.log(totalIt(arr));  //[17, 10, 19]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming array is static as op showned.

```js
a = [
      [0, 1, 3],
      [2, 4, 6],
      [5, 5, 7],
      [10, 0, 3]
    ]

b = []
      
for(i = 0; i < a[0].length; i++){      
  count = 0
  for(j = 0; j < a.length; j++){    
     count += a[j][i]   
   }
   b.push(count)
}  
console.log(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

So far, no answer using the `for ... of` mentioned in the question.
I've used a conditional statement for different lengths of inner arrays.

```js
var a = [
  [0, 1, 3],
  [2, 4, 6],
  [5, 5, 7],
  [10, 0, 3]
];
i = 0;
r = []
for (const inner of a) {
  j = 0;
  for (const num of inner) {
    if (j == r.length) r.push(num)
    else r[j] += num
    j++;
  }
  i++;
}
console.log(r);
```

True, in this case, the classic `for` cycle fits better than `for ... of`.
The following snippet uses a conditional (ternary) operator.

```js
var a = [
  [0, 1, 3],
  [2, 4, 6],
  [5, 5, 7],
  [10, 0, 3]
];

r = [];
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
    j==r.length ? r.push(a[i][j]) : r[j]+=a[i][j]
  }
}

console.log(r);
```

A solution using maps and reductions, adding elements from different lengths of arrays.

```js
var array = [
  [0],
  [2, 4],
  [5, 5, 7, 10, 20, 30],
  [10, 0]
];
b = Array(array.reduce((a, b) => Math.max(a, b.length), 0)).fill(0);
result = array.reduce((r, a) => b.map((_, i) => (a[i] || 0) + (r[i] || 0)), []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
const ar = [
  [0, 1, 3],
  [2, 4, 6],
  [5, 5, 7],
  [10, 0, 3]
]   

ar.map( item => item.reduce( (memo, value)=> memo+= value, 0 ) )
//result-> [4, 12, 17, 13]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: This does not answer the question, it sums every array.