# Make the average of array data

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, average

I'm stuck on how to realize this relative simple operation in Javascript:

I have a list of object defined in this way:

```
[
    {id: 1, region: "America", country:"USA", values:[1,2,3,4] },
    {id: 2, region: "America", country:"Canada", values:[3,4,5,6] },
    {id: 3, region: "Europe", country:"France", values:[1,2,3,4] },
    {id: 4, region: "Europe", country:"Italy", values:[1,2,3,4] },
    {id: 5, region: "Europe", country:"Spain", values:[5,9,1,7] },
    {id: 6, region: "Europe", country:"Germany", values:[1,6,2,8] },
    {id: 7, region: "Europe", country:"Ireland", values:[6,4,6,9]}
      ]
```

I'm trying to make an average of the numbers contined in the value field, grouped by the region.
So to the above list I will have two more elements, one for America and one for Europe, containing the average of the values:

```
[
    {id: 1, region: "America", country:"USA", values:[1,2,3,4] },
    {id: 2, region: "America", country:"Canada", values:[3,4,5,6] },
    {id: 3, region: "Europe", country:"France", values:[1,2,3,4] },
    {id: 4, region: "Europe", country:"Italy", values:[1,2,3,4] },
    {id: 5, region: "Europe", country:"Spain", values:[5,9,1,7] },
    {id: 6, region: "Europe", country:"Germany", values:[1,6,2,8] },
    {id: 7, region: "Europe", country:"Ireland", values:[6,4,6,9]},
    {id: 8, region: "America", country:"avg", values:[2,3,4,5]},
    {id: 9, region: "Europe", country:"avg", values:[2.8,4.6,2.8,6.4]}
      ]
```

Any idea on how to do it?
Please keep in mind that the number of elements to aggregate could be around 10~15 and the numbers in value fields can be around 150~200
value field contains the same number of values for all the elements.
Some value could be null, so in this case I need to calculate the averages consequently, as null is not 0!

I could do a lot of loops to scan everything and make the calculation, but I'm wondering if there is something easier and faster, keeping good performances.

---

Explanation/Example:
The first average value for America would be calculated as follows:

```
(sum of first value of 'values' for each country with region 'America')
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
            (number of countries with region 'America')
```

Pseudo code:

```
America.avg.values[0] = (USA.values[0] + Canada.values[0]) / 2 /*(1+3)/2 = 2*/;
America.avg.values[1] = (USA.values[1] + Canada.values[1]) / 2 /*(2+4)/2 = 3*/;
...
```

Comment: @Andreas yes it's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduce the original data, keeping track of intermediate results in an object:

- Object makes a new key for every new region it comes across
- When the first data entry for a region is considered, store two things:

  - The average, which starts as a copy of the values of the first item
  - The count that the average represents, which starts at 1
- When a second or n'th item appears, calculate a new average using a moving average formula
- Return the result object until all entries are processed
- Convert the object to two data points and concat them to the original array

```js
var data = [
    {id: 1, region: "America", country:"USA", values:[1,2,null,4] },
    {id: 2, region: "America", country:"Canada", values:[3,4,5,6] },
    {id: 3, region: "Europe", country:"France", values:[1,2,3,4] },
    {id: 4, region: "Europe", country:"Italy", values:[1,2,3,4] },
    {id: 5, region: "Europe", country:"Spain", values:[5,9,1,7] },
    {id: 6, region: "Europe", country:"Germany", values:[1,6,2,8] },
    {id: 7, region: "Europe", country:"Ireland", values:[6,4,6,9]}
];

var avg = data.reduce(function(result, current) {
  if (result[current.region]) {
    var obj = result[current.region];
    obj.avg = current.values
      // Map to a moving average: 
      //  - the current avg at pos `i` represents `count` samples
      .map(function(v, i) { 
        if (v === null) return obj.avg[i];
      
        return (v + (obj.avg[i] * obj.count[i])) / (++obj.count[i]);
       });
  } else {
    result[current.region] = {
      count: current.values.map(function(v) { 
        return v !== null ? 1 : 0; 
      }),
      avg: current.values.map(function(v) {
        return v !== null ? v : 0;
      })
    };
  }
  
  return result;
}, {});

// Add to array (assume sorted by id)
var extendedData = data.concat(Object.keys(avg).map(function(k, i) {
  return {
    id: data[data.length - 1].id + 1 + i,
    region: k,
    country: "avg",
    values: avg[k].avg
  };
}));

console.log(extendedData);
```

Comment: Thanks it's perfect and also the map-reduce approach is very nice. The right term for this question should be Moving Average... you're right.

Comment: I found an issue when there is a null value, so no data available... like this:    {id: 1, region: "America", country:"USA", values:[1,2,null,4] },
    {id: 2, region: "America", country:"Canada", values:[3,4,5,6] } should result as 2,3,5,5

Comment: Ah, I figured you'd want `null` values to be treated as `0`... Didn't see that requirement. Easy fix though, I'll make an edit.

Comment: I've fixed it by making `count` an array as well. Now, each value index can have its own count, which means that when `null` is in a value set, that value index' count won't be incremented.

Comment: Yes now it's perfect, I was trying to fix it but I still need to understand how the map-reduce works! Thanks

Comment: `map` is a way to do two things at once: you use an array to create a new array of equal length, while processing its values using the function it is passed. The great thing about `reduce` is that it allows you to loop over an array while returning a value to the next iteration. Let me know if there are certain lines in this snippet that need clarification; I'm happy to add comments or provide alternative ways of writing stuff down if it's needed!

Answer (score 3):

You could use an object for keeping sum and count of elements and assign the average on each loop of the values to the grouped object.

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, region: "America", country: "USA", values: [1, 2, 3, 4] }, { id: 2, region: "America", country: "Canada", values: [3, 4, 5, 6] }, { id: 3, region: "Europe", country: "France", values: [1, 2, 3, 4] }, { id: 4, region: "Europe", country: "Italy", values: [1, 2, 3, 4] }, { id: 5, region: "Europe", country: "Spain", values: [5, 9, 1, 7] }, { id: 6, region: "Europe", country: "Germany", values: [1, 6, 2, 8] }, { id: 7, region: "Europe", country: "Ireland", values: [6, 4, 6, 9] }];

data.forEach(function (a, i, aa) {
    if (!this[a.region]) {
        this[a.region] = { sum: [], count: [], values: [] };
        aa.push({ id: aa.length + 1, region: a.region, country: 'avg', values: this[a.region].values });
    }
    a.values.forEach(function (b, i) {
        if (b !== null) {
            this[a.region].sum[i] = (this[a.region].sum[i] || 0) + b;
            this[a.region].count[i] = (this[a.region].count[i] || 0) + 1;
            this[a.region].values[i] = this[a.region].sum[i] / this[a.region].count[i];
        }
    }, this);
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Just for the last `Europe` avg value: `6.25 !== 6.4`; Also the "average objects" have `America` and `Europe`. I doubt your algorithm fits the requirement

Comment: @Andreas is right, is not what I must do, I don't need to make the average of the number in value field, too simple!! see the expected results in the question

Comment: @Giox Is the calculation in my comment on your question correct? If so you might add it in your question as an example

Comment: @Andreas yes exactly what I need! but consider that I can't hard-code the region name as they are dynamic

Comment: @Nina Scholz could it be similar to what you have succesfully answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34458132/how-to-sum-elements-at-the-same-index-in-array-of-arrays-into-a-single-array/34458168#34458168 using the reduce method

Comment: @Giox, do you need the total sum and avg? what should happen to nul values? how does it look like in your data?

Comment: @NinaScholz you're very close to the solution, you rock! but the result avg values must be of the same lenght of the original, look at the edit done to the question. I need only AVG and when there is a null value I dont have to consider in the avg count: (2+4+null)/2=3

Comment: @NinaScholz perfect

Answer (score 0):

I would just Loop through the entire array and count the avg of values, then add an `avg` property to the array.

```js
var data = [
    {id: 1, region: "America", country:"USA", values:[1,2,3,4] },
    {id: 2, region: "America", country:"Canada", values:[3,4,5,6] },
    {id: 3, region: "Europe", country:"France", values:[1,2,3,4] },
    {id: 4, region: "Europe", country:"Italy", values:[1,2,3,4] },
    {id: 5, region: "Europe", country:"Spain", values:[5,9,1,7] },
    {id: 6, region: "Europe", country:"Germany", values:[1,6,2,8] },
    {id: 7, region: "Europe", country:"Ireland", values:[6,4,6,9]}
];

data.forEach(function(element,index,array){
  var sum = 0;
  element.values.forEach(function(element,index,array){
    sum += element;
  });
  element.avg = sum / element.values.length;
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: no, it's wrong, doesn't fit the requirements. It makes the average of the countries and not of the regions. See the expected result in the question

Answer (score 0):

You can so something like this:

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, region: "America", country: "USA", values: [1, 2, null, 4] }, { id: 2, region: "America", country: "Canada", values: [3, 4, 5, 6] }, { id: 3, region: "Europe", country: "France", values: [1, 2, 3, 4] }, { id: 4, region: "Europe", country: "Italy", values: [1, 2, 3, 4] }, { id: 5, region: "Europe", country: "Spain", values: [5, 9, 1, 7] }, { id: 6, region: "Europe", country: "Germany", values: [1, 6, 2, 8] }, { id: 7, region: "Europe", country: "Ireland", values: [6, 4, 6, 9] }]

// So that regions are configurable
var regions = ['America', 'Europe'];
var result = [];

// for cases when data is not sorted by id.
var lastIndex = Math.max.apply(null, data.map(function(x){ return x.id}))

regions.forEach(function(r) {
  var val = [];
  data.forEach(function(c,i){
    if(c.region === r && c.values && c.values.length > 0){
      c.values.forEach(function(v, i) {
        if (!v && v!== 0) return
          val[i] = (val[i] || []);
          val[i].push(v)
      })
    }
  });
  
  var avg = val.map(function(v){
    return (v.reduce(function(p,c){ return p+c }) / v.length);
  })
  
  // not pushing into data to prevent extra iterations
  result.push({
    id: ++lastIndex,
    region: r,
    country: 'avg',
    values: avg
  })

});

data = data.concat(result)
console.log(data)
```

Comment: You're close but... _"when there is a null value I don't have to consider in the avg count: (2+4+null)/2=3"_

Comment: @Andreas Are you taking about case where `values` length is variable?

Comment: The `values` array can contain `null` and in this case this should not be treated as `0` (`(val[i] || 0)`) and it should not increment the number of elements (`len++`) - at least that's my interpretation of the question and the comment of the TO...

Comment: [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/n2nz6en6/1/). And thanks for baring with me. I have updated condition in my answer to `!v && v!== 0`

Answer (score 0):

Below is a general solution that will work for any number of regions.  I know the question is ages old (2 hours), but consider the simplicity of the approach.  For every unique region, calculate the average as such:

1 - get all `values` arrays as one 2d array for the given region
2 - transpose this array
3 - average each array

```
var data = // your array here

function getArr(data,reg) {
    return data.filter(el => el.region === reg)
               .map(el => el.values)
}

const xpose = x => x[0].map( (c,i) => x.map( r => r[i] ) )

function avgArr(a) {
    a = a.filter(el => el !== null);
    return a.reduce((x,y) => x+y) / a.length;
}

function calcAverages(data) {
    let i = 1 + Math.max.apply(null, data.map( el => el.id )) // max id
    let regions = [...new Set (data.map (a => a.region))]  // unique regions

    regions.forEach( region => {
        data.push( { id: i++,
                     region: region,
                     country: "avg",
                     values: xpose(getArr(data,region)).map(a => avgArr(a))})})

    return data
}

// > calcAverages(data)
//
// ...
//  { id: 8,
//    region: 'America',
//    country: 'avg',
//    values: [ 2, 3, 4, 5 ] },
//  { id: 9,
//    region: 'Europe',
//    country: 'avg',
//    values: [ 2.8, 4.6, 3, 6.4 ] } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to do as follows

```js
var data = [
    {id: 1, region: "America", country:"USA", values:[1,2,3,4] },
    {id: 2, region: "America", country:"Canada", values:[3,4,5,6] },
    {id: 3, region: "Europe", country:"France", values:[1,2,3,4] },
    {id: 4, region: "Europe", country:"Italy", values:[1,2,3,4] },
    {id: 5, region: "Europe", country:"Spain", values:[5,9,1,7] },
    {id: 6, region: "Europe", country:"Germany", values:[1,6,2,8] },
    {id: 7, region: "Europe", country:"Ireland", values:[6,4,6,9]}
      ],
 newData = [...new Set(data.map(c => c.region))]
           .reduce((f,c,i) => (f.push(...data.filter(o => o.region === c)
                                             .reduce((p,q,_,a) => { p[0].values = q.values.map((v,j) => v/a.length + p[0].values[j]);
                                                                    p.push(q);
                                                                    return p;
                                                                  } ,[{     id: data.length + 1 + i,
                                                                        region: c,
                                                                       country: "avg",
                                                                        values: Array(data[0].values.length).fill(0)
                                                                      }])),f),[]);
console.log(newData);
```