# Sum of one index in multiple arrays using .reduce

Tags: arrays, angularjs, indexing, sum

The picture below shows the arrays I am pulling from HealthKit's step counter. The arrays have step count values of 33 + 97 + 75.

[Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KB86M.png)

I'm not sure how to grab the second index in each array and add them together to get 205.

**I am currently using:**

let stepSum = (data as any).reduce((a, b) => a + b.quantity, 0);

**This logs arrays correctly :**

console.log(data as any);

**This** link below is the closest thing I could find, but I am not sure how to apply it to only one index. [How to sum elements at the same index in array of arrays into a single array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34458132/how-to-sum-elements-at-the-same-index-in-array-of-arrays-into-a-single-array)

Thanks in advance for any help!

I am using Ionic Framework (HTML/CSS files) and Angular (TS files).

Comment: Share your data and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function you can write,

```js
function sum(data, value){
    return data.reduce( function(a, b){
        return a + b[value];
    }, 0);
};

var data = [{ startDate: '', endDate: '', value: 33},
{ startDate: '', endDate: '', value: 97},
{ startDate: '', endDate: '', value: 75}]

alert(sum(data, 'value'))
```

**Please run the above snippet**

**If you want ts:**

```
function sum(data, value){
    return data.reduce((a, b) => {
        return a + b[value];
    }, 0);
};
```