# Summing by index reference a group of arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function that needs to take an array from each in a group of documents, and sum each position in each array with it's index 'partner' at the [n]th position.

The arrays look something like this......

```
[300, 230, 45, 0, 0, 0]
[200, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
...
```

From which I would want to return [502, 331, 45, 0, 0, 0]. Using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34458132/how-to-sum-elements-at-the-same-index-in-array-of-arrays-into-a-single-array) which is asking almost the same thing, I copied a reduce function, so my function now looks like this...

```
this.projects.forEach(function (project) {
    let arrays = project.yearsTotal
    result = arrays.reduce(function (r, a) {
        a.forEach(function (b, i) {
            r[i] = (r[i] || 0) + b;
        });
        return r
    }, []);
 })
```

However, this tells me that 'a.forEach is not a function', I must admit that I'm not sure exactly what the reduce function is doing, but I think perhaps that it isn't working because my arrays are not an *array of arrays*, they exist separately.

Javascript tells me they are objects, not arrays, but I'm not sure that is significant. Please could someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: please add the original data. btw, you never use `result`. it is not declared as well.

Comment: You are nesting the loop three times but you need only twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference with the question you linked seems to be your numeric data, that is stored inside array of objects (in property `yearsTotal`) - and not in array of arrays of numbers.

If that's the case, you can just create another array storing only the values you need:

```
const projectYearsTotal = this.projects.map(p => p.yearsTotal);
```

... and then you can proceed with reduce-forEach-ing it.

Your current solution tries to 'zip-sum' the array of numbers (value of 'yearsTotal' of each individual project), not array of arrays of numbers. Hence `forEach is not a function` error.